Could someone alias [tag:dissasembler] (see spelling) to [tag:disassembler], please?
Subject line says it all: Could someone alias dissasembler (see spelling) to disassembler, please?
The former just got inadvertently created by someone posting a question. I fixed that by giving the correct spelling.
Of course I don't know whether this is the right way to go about this or whether it is sufficient to "delete" the misspelled version?! 

There is no need for misspelled versions of a tag. As the tag has now been removed (and is not used by any question), it will get deleted in some time.
Also, as we are following the policy of having plural tags, disassemblers created. 

I see. Didn't know the mechanics in that.

shouldn't tag be plurals by default btw?

@Ange Not unless their first use was plural. If it was singular, then they have to be done manually.
